# conn (net.Conn) does not write always on socket

Tags: sockets, go, tcp, byte

I have done an application with a server and client to send information with a socket TCP

The problem is, if the function zfs.ReceiveSnapshot (in server side) does not return an error (err == nil), `conn.Write([]byte("0"))` does not work and the client does not receive any byte to continue and it cannot close the connection...

I show you the code of server and client

**Server:**

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "github.com/mistifyio/go-zfs"
)

func main() {
    // Listen for incoming connections
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":7766")

    // Close the listener when the application closes
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Listening on port 7766...")
    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, _ := l.Accept()
        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

// Handles incoming requests
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    // Receive snapshot
    _, err := zfs.ReceiveSnapshot(conn, "tank/replication")
    if err != nil {
        conn.Write([]byte("1"))
        zfs.ReceiveSnapshot(conn, "tank/replication")
        conn.Close()
    } else {
        conn.Write([]byte("0"))
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "github.com/mistifyio/go-zfs"
)

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.99.5:7766")

    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        // Get all snapshots in tank/test
        take, _ := zfs.Snapshots("tank/test")

        // Select snapshots
        snap := take[0].Name
        ds1, _ := zfs.GetDataset(snap)

        // Send first snapshot
        ds1.SendSnapshot(conn)
        defer conn.Close()

        buff := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, _ := conn.Read(buff)

        if n != 0 {
            snap = take[1].Name
            ds2, _ := zfs.GetDataset(snap)
            zfs.SendSnapshotIncremental(conn, ds1, ds2, zfs.IncrementalStream)
            conn.Close()
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT]:
If `ReceiveSnapshots` returns an error, conn.Write([]byte ) writes "1", the cliente receives it, execute SendSnapshotIncremental (it does if n != 0) and close the connection in client side... But, if `ReceiveSnapshot` does not return an error, conn.Write([]byte ) does not write "0" just only I close the connection in server side with ctrl+C

Comment: Are you checking the error from `Dial` on the client side? I am assuming the client is connecting if things are running the ReceiveSnapshot parts.

Comment: Receiving another snapshot on error feels odd as well, but probably isn't your issue.

Comment: @OliviaRuth Yes, `Dial` works fine. If err != nil, conn.Write([]byte) returns the "1", the client receives it and close the connection. The problem is when err == <nil>, the client receive anything...

Comment: Why is buf of size 1024 on the client side? Does it change at all if you make it size 1?

Comment: If there's a connection error in `ReceiveSnapshot`, you're still trying to write to the connection, which isn't going to get sent anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit & Solved]

Several modifications to solve this...

**Server:**

```
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    // Number of snapshots in server side
    take, _ := zfs.Snapshots("tank/replication")
    count := len(take)
    if count < 1 {
        conn.Write([]byte("0"))
    } else {
        conn.Write([]byte("1"))
    }

    // Receive snapshot
    zfs.ReceiveSnapshot(conn, "tank/replication")
}
```

`count` returns the number of snapshots that server has, so if there are nothing, the client will execute the case, in other case the default.

**Client:**

```
func main() {
    // Get the last two snapshots
    take, _ := zfs.Snapshots("tank/test")
    snap := take[0].Name
    ds1, _ := zfs.GetDataset(snap)
    snap = take[1].Name
    ds2, _ := zfs.GetDataset(snap)

    // New server connection
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.99.5:7766")

    // Read data of server side
    buff := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    n, _ := buff.ReadByte()

    // Execute the correct case
    switch string(n) {
    case "0":
        ds1.SendSnapshot(conn)
        conn.Close()
    default :
        zfs.SendSnapshotIncremental(conn, ds1, ds2, zfs.IncrementalStream)
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's so good this solution but it works!

Comment: @JimB But under that premise, we can't use a socket TCP to send data because it exists the possibility that the tunnel will break. I dont't really understand what you want to say :S

Comment: No, it just means that messages aren't read as atomic units, because there's no such thing as a "message" in TCP. You need a framing protocol of some sort to delimit the messages so that you know you've read only the part of the message you intended, and part or more than 1 message. Your protocol could simply be "send one byte" and you could read and compare that byte instead of throwing it away.

Comment: So you say, read the buffer and the extract the information to know if I received all message that I want receive.
That is, I should change the conn.Write to "1" and "22" and read if I have received all of thats messages. That will be right @JimB?

Comment: Instead of adding extra logic to determine how much to read  for a simple binary message, just use 1 byte. Write `0` or `1`, then read a single byte and compare it to `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in these lines:

```
buff := make([]byte, 1024)
n, _ := conn.Read(buff)
```

n in this case is the **number** of bytes read, not the value of any of them.

I'd do:

```
buff := make([]byte, 1)
n,err := conn.Read(buff)
buff = buff[:n]
if len(buff) == 0 {
   //error
}

if(buff[0] != 0){...
```

Comment: Whenever you `Read` you always need to check `n`, because you can read into buff and get EOF in the same operation.

Comment: If the first function `ReceiveSnapshot` returns an error, conn.Write([]byte("1")) works fine and the client receive the "1" and continue with the if n != 0 {... zfs.SendSnapshotIncremental...}.
But, if the first `ReceiveSnapshot` does not return an error, (conn.Write[]byte("0")) does not work and the client receive anything...

Comment: That seems completely backwards from what you would normally want to do, @icvallejo. On an error condition, you continue writing data to sockets that may be in closed/error states.

Comment: @OliviaRuth: that's still going to skip `n > 0 && err == io.EOF`, just process `buff[:n]` (or check `n > 0`) then check `err`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I don't like that behavior at all.

Comment: @OliviaRuth If `ReceiveSnapshot` returns an error it's not a problem. It's only to verify if the Snapshot that it has received exist or not.

Comment: But it could be a connectivity problem as well. How are you so sure "The client receives nothing"? How are you running/debugging this?

Comment: ok, this answer is not the issue then. I want to blame something like `SetNoDelay`, but the default should not be causing this.

Comment: @OliviaRuth I edited the original post to explain the problem better